# Determining if object property name is a number

Tags: javascript, json, coffeescript

Having an `Object` with multiple attribute properties

```
{
  ...,
  attributes:{
  [0]: "Capricorn One",
  [1]: "Total Recall",
  "name": "Jerry Goldsmith"
 }
}
```

i want to determine which of them are numeric keys and which are not.

Currently i am doing this like:

```
for d of data.attributes
  prop =  parseInt(d)
  if !_.isNaN(prop)
    # property is a number
```

and i wonder if is there a better/more efficient way of doing the same thing?

Comment: Note that the for... of expression is experimental and it may change its syntax or behavior in the future. The compability is limited, read more here: [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FStatements%2Ffor...of)

Comment: @estrar No it's not.  That's the CoffeeScript `for...of`, which compiles to the javascript `for...in`.

Comment: @AaronDufour You're right, my bad! That's quite confusing though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The approach you already have is good, but you can trim it down a little by removing the `parseInt` call. `isNaN` will do that for you:

```
for d of data.attributes
  if !_.isNaN(d)
    # property is a number
```

From [the spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1.2.4) (emphasis added):

> Returns true if the argument **coerces** to NaN, and otherwise returns false.
>
> 1. If **ToNumber(*number*)** is NaN, return true.
> 2. Otherwise, return false.

You could also use the native `isNaN` instead of the Underscore version, since `d` is never going to be `undefined`:

```
for d of data.attributes
  if !isNaN(d)
    # property is a number
```

Comment: how can you write such a useful response in 3 minutes? :)